# Cache handling with RXJava

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to implement this workflow with rxJava but i'm sure if i'm misusing or doing stuff wrong.

- User asks to login
- If a loginResult is available in cache then "emit" the cached LoginResult
- Else actually perform the request to the webservice and cache the result if everything is successfull
- If an error occurs retry at most 3 times and if there is a 4th time then purge the cache.

Here is my full snippet of code.

```
public class LoginTask extends BaseBackground<LoginResult> {
  private static CachedLoginResult cachedLoginResult = new CachedLoginResult();
  private XMLRPCClient xmlrpcClient;
  private UserCredentialsHolder userCredentialsHolder;

  @Inject
  public LoginTask(XMLRPCClient client, UserCredentialsHolder userCredentialsHolder) {
    this.xmlrpcClient = client;
    this.userCredentialsHolder = userCredentialsHolder;
  }

  @Override
  public LoginResult performRequest() throws Exception {
    return UserApi.login(
        xmlrpcClient,
        userCredentialsHolder.getUserName(),
        userCredentialsHolder.getPlainPassword());


  }

  @Override
  public Observable<LoginResult> getObservable() {
    return cachedLoginResult.getObservable()
        .onErrorResumeNext(
            Observable.create(
                ((Observable.OnSubscribe<LoginResult>) subscriber -> {
                  try {
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                      subscriber.onNext(performRequest()); // actually performRequest
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                  } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                  }
                })
            )
                .doOnNext(cachedLoginResult::setLoginResult)
                .retry((attempts, t) -> attempts < 3)
                .doOnError(throwable -> cachedLoginResult.purgeCache())
        );
  }


  private static class CachedLoginResult {
    private LoginResult lr = null;
    private long when = 0;

    private CachedLoginResult() {
    }

    public boolean hasCache() {
      return lr != null && when + TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES) > System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void setLoginResult(LoginResult lr) {
      if (lr != null) {
          this.lr = lr;
          this.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
      }
    }

    public void purgeCache() {
      this.lr = null;
      this.when = 0;
    }

    public Observable<LoginResult> getObservable() {
      return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super LoginResult> subscriber) {
          if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            if (hasCache()) {
              subscriber.onNext(lr);
              subscriber.onCompleted();
            } else {
              subscriber.onError(new RuntimeException("No cache"));
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Since i wan't able to find any similar examples and i started "playing" with rxjava just 1 day ago i'm unsure of my implementation.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code is alright, good job :)

You were right to use `Observable.create` in your `LoginTask` because otherwise result of the call could be cached internally, and then `retry` wouldn't help much...

This is I think however unnecessary for the `CachedLoginResult`'s `Observable`. Here you can simplify your code by using `Observable.just`and `Observable.error` utility methods, something like:

```
public Observable<LoginResult> getObservable() {
  if (hasCache()) {
      return Observable.just(lr);
  } else {
      return Observable.error(new RuntimeException("No cache"));
  }
}
```

Note: `just` stores the value you tell it to emit internally, so that resubscriptions will always produce this value. This is what I hinted above, you shouldn't do `Observable.just(performRequest()).retry(3)` for example, because the `performRequest` will only ever be called once.

Comment: Hello Simon, correct if 'm wrong but using your .just and .error will cause the value to be emitted at observable creation. What happens if I create the main observable and use it after the cache expires? I guess it will just return me the 30mins older cache which should be expired by now right?

Comment: you are right, just will capture the value of the cache at the moment you call getObservable(), so a `Observable.create` or `Observable.defer` would actually make sense. Also have a look at Akarnokd's answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to perform the login once and cache the result in a reactive manner? If so, here is an example how I would do this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

import rx.*;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.subjects.AsyncSubject;


public class CachingLogin {
    static class LoginResult {

    }
    /** Guarded by this. */
    AsyncSubject<LoginResult> cache;
    public Observable<LoginResult> login(String username, String password) {
        AsyncSubject<LoginResult> c;
        boolean doLogin = false;
        synchronized (this) {
            if (cache == null || cache.hasThrowable()) {
                cache = AsyncSubject.create();
                doLogin = true;
            }
            c = cache;
        }
        if (doLogin) {
            Observable.just(1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(v -> loginAPI(username, password))
            .retry(3).subscribe(c);
        }
        return c;
    }
    public void purgeCache() {
        synchronized (this) {
            cache = null;
        }
    }
    static LoginResult loginAPI(String username, String password) {
        if (ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble() < 0.3) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed");
        }
        return new LoginResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello akarnokd, thank you for your answer. It looks like a good way to do things in rxjava :) IF i understand it correctly when you call your "login" method, it will trigger the loginAPI() immediately (if cache is not present). While this could make sense in most scenarios i'd like to get the observable that kicks the real http call so that i can use observeOn and subscribeOn depending on the use-case.